# How to add products automatically to Draft when import through API

Tags: woocommerce

I have an online store and we sell products (dropshipping) from different supplier.
One of the supplier import products to our store with API and all products are published automatically. But I want to check the name, images...etc before we publish the products, so it would be good if all of the products first stay in draft mode.
I have found this code on the internet but when I use it, the products are going to draft mode so that is good, but I can not publish the product from draft (publish button doesn't work).
I would appreciate if someone could help with this issue.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'post_insert_handler', '99', 2 );
function post_insert_handler($data,$postarr) {
if (strpos($data["post_type"],"product")===0) $data["post_status"] = "draft";
return $data;
}
```

Comment: it's not working because when you edit a product and try to publish the product this `wp_insert_post_data` same hook will be called. so every time you will try to publish status will remain the same as the draft? Which plugin you are using to import data through API? or this is custom code?

Comment: Set post status on import its self.

Comment: @Bhautik, it is not a plugin, I generated an API keys and gave it to them. I have some settings on their website (what I want to synch for example) but nothing else, that is why I want to have the items in draft first before I check and publish the products.